# Authorization header not being sent in AJAX request

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I'm having issues properly sending an Authorization header along with an AJAX request. I've read that this might be a CORS issue, but I believe everything is configured correctly. Here's the code on the client side:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: <location>,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {"Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token},
        success: function (user) {
            Cookies.set('user', user, {expires: 1});
        }
    });
```

And here's the some of the code for the server side (using Express). Middleware for CORS:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin || "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next();
});
```

And my middleware to check for the Authorization header:

```
 app.use(function (req, res, next) {
        var config, authorization;

        authorization = req.get('authorization');
        if (!authorization) throw new NoAuthenticationError();
...
```

But nada.

When I examine the headers from the second middleware, I noticed that `req.headers` contains `access-control-request-headers: "accept, authorization"` but the explicit Authorization header doesn't exist from the server end.

Any ideas?

**Edit**: I've now realized that I have to handle jQuery's initial preflight OPTIONS request separately. I'll do that and report back...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, it's as I suspected in my edit. I needed to just handle the OPTIONS request by only sending back the CORS headers:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.headers.origin || "*");
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, HEAD, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
        return res.end();
    }
    next();
});
```